# Generating SOAP Response XML from WSDL 2.0 in Java

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soapui

My project requirement is to generate SOAP Response XML from wsdl (2.0 and 1.1) like in SOAPUI.
What are libraries (Java APIs), I can use to generate response xml? 
Does it also support WSDL 2.0?
Are there any approach to satisfy the requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to use Apache CXF. It is a very good framework for creating web services. Add in Spring and Maven and you have some solid frameworks for creating soap services without doing all the messy work yourself.

http://cxf.apache.org/

Comment: The project is based on core Java. User selects the wsdl file and he just needs the response xml (like in SOAPUI) to be generated for a particular operation. For WSDL Parsing I am using EasyWSDL. Not sure if it is possible to generate an XML(request/response) from it.

Comment: @winaykumar: If you have solved this, please post the code/link to the same. This would help others.